# Pass unsigned char * by reference

Tags: objective-c, c

HI! I create a function to get a grayscale version of an image, but i have problem trying to  pass by reference the destination of the bit(s) generated by this function:

```
void grayscale (const unsigned char *source, unsigned char **dest, int data_size) {

    for (int i=0; i < data_size; i= i+4) {
        int gray = (source[i] + source[i+1] + source[i+2]) / 3;
        gray = 255 - (int)cos(source[i])*255;
        *dest[i] = (char)gray;
        *dest[i + 1] = (char)gray;
        *dest[i + 2] = (char)gray; //HERE AN ERROR 
        *dest[i + 3] = (char)255;
    }
}
```

I call this function with:

```
grayscale(source, &destination, width*height*4 );
```

Is there something wrong with pointers ? 
(i'm working on objective C and i obtain a EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Thank you

Comment: what is `destination`? how big is it?

Comment: Just because an error is detected on a line doesn't mean its cause is there. Please post a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using an additional level of indirection for `dest`, since `*dest` is not being modified but most likely you need to do the following - change:

```
    *dest[i] = (char)source[i];
    *dest[i + 1] = (char)gray;
    *dest[i + 2] = (char)gray;
    *dest[i + 3] = (char)255;
```

to:

```
    (*dest)[i] = (char)source[i];
    (*dest)[i + 1] = (char)gray;
    (*dest)[i + 2] = (char)gray; 
    (*dest)[i + 3] = (char)255;
```

The reason for this is operator precedence/associativity.

Also it's hard to tell without seeing the calling code, but I'm guessing you may need to change:

```
    (*dest)[i] = (char)source[i];
```

to:

```
    (*dest)[i] = (char)source[i / 4];
```

if you're trying to do something like convert a single plane image to RGBA.

Comment: I correct the code... is not (char)source[i] ... but simply (char)gray;

Comment: Thank you! the error is on my wrong management of operator precedence. I feel ashamed asking that but... can someone tell me how to get the size of "source" variable ? there's something like a count() function that i can call on "source" ? i tried with strlen but the value isn't the last index of source.  
thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Your call is fine, you have an illegal memory access. Debug your indices and check the size of the array your passing in, also check that it is still in scope. Most likely i+2 is out of bounds.

Comment: I bet if you modify the terminating condition in your for loot to be i < data_size - 4 it will work. Nice try at loop unrolling, just remember to change the conditions for the loop!

Comment: I don't think it's loop unrolling - it looks like a conversion such as grey scale to RGBA or similar.

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing the calling code and variable declarations etc, but I think it's actually an operator precedence/associativity problem (see my answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments. I'm sure that the loop is correct because i started from an identical function that return directly and unsigned char * instead of modify its value by reference and it works without error.